# Joining two tables for delete using DeltaTable

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have an use case, where I have a file path which has "company_id" and "date".
Have another s3 file where I need to delete data which is below year 2010 based on "company_id" and "date" of first file.

Second file has many columns including "company_id","date" and "year".

How this can be achieved , i tried this but not giving an error.

**Tried :**

```
val source="s3a://source_table"
val target="s3a://target_table"


val source_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, source)
val target_delta = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, target)


target_delta .alias("a")
      .merge(
        source_delta .alias("b"),
        condition=( ($"b.company_id" === $"a.company_id") and  ($"b.data" === $"a.date") and ($"a.year" <= "2010") )
        )
      .whenMatched().delete()
      .execute()

println("Done")
```

**Error :**

```
command-4296412619890660:18: error: overloaded method value merge with alternatives:
  (source: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder <and>
  (source: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,condition: String)io.delta.tables.DeltaMergeBuilder
 cannot be applied to (io.delta.tables.DeltaTable, condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
      .merge(
       ^
```

Comment: Add your code and error details.

Comment: @JayashankarGS added code snippet. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dataframe as source not a delta table.

Use source like below.

```
import  io.delta.tables._

val  source_delta = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "src")
val  target_delta = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "tar")

target_delta.alias("a").merge(
    source_delta.toDF.alias("b"),
    "b.company_id=a.company_id")
    .whenMatched().delete().execute()
```

[image]

Matched `company_id` are removed.

Before merge.

[image]

After merge.

[image]

Source having company id 3 and 4.

Comment: thanks a lot. let me try it , why used forName i.e. DeltaTable.forName instead forPath ??

Comment: There is nothing to do with forName and ForPath both retrieve deltatable.

Comment: The issue lies in the df you are giving inside merge. You need to give `(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)` or `(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,string)` instead you are giving `(io.delta.tables.DeltaTable,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)`.

Below is the function definitions.
`def Evolvingmerge(source: DataFrame, condition: Column): DeltaMergeBuilder`,
`def Evolvingmerge(source: DataFrame, condition: String): DeltaMergeBuilder`

Comment: @JayashankarGS thanks a lot , you are from hyd?